# Could I have broken my light fixture whilst changing the light bulb?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, light

Ok, so not proficient in changing light bulbs... I have taken out the bulb before and put it back in so I know how to do it. I wanted to put in an adaptor so I could put in a colour changing bulb. I thought the adaptor was the same as the bulb I currently have but it wouldn't push in and then twist ( I have a bayonet lightbulb and fixture). Now I have put the bulb back in but it won't light up. Also I have now flicked the switch so much I don't know if the electricity is on or off. What should I do? I know not to fiddle anymore! Don't want to get electrocuted... do I need an electrician????

Comment: Bayonet sockets do have smaller metal contacts that can bend.  If the original light bulb doesn't work, you probably have your answer.  Look close at the socket and look for bent contacts.  You may be able to bend them back **with the switch turned off**.

Comment: Thank You :) very helpful will give it a go tomorrow

Comment: This is especially easy to do if its a cheaper/lighter fitting, has plastic or bakelite  parts, or if you had to use excessive force at any point.  Did any bits crack or fall out of the holder?   You might want to replace the fitment for peace of mind, if you have any doubts.